# submit the form without submit button

Tags: jquery

I want to submit the form without using submit button
form looks like

```
 <form method="post" action="action.php">
// somany divs
<input type="hidden" name="ivlue" value="er">
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
   $("form").trigger("submit");    
})
</script>
```

and also tried 
      `$("form").submit();`

But this code doesn't submit the form.

Comment: did you try $("form").submit() instead?

Comment: Try `$("submit").click();`

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").trigger("submit");    
});
$('form').on('submit', function() { alert("ya"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="action.php">
  // somany divs
  <input type="hidden" name="ivlue" value="er">
  <input type="submit" style="display:none">
</form>
```

In firefox you need the submit button. You can hide it, but needs to be present.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit you can use this code which is not using jquery, it is the plain js function

```
document.forms["formname"].submit();
```

And you need to have a form, which you identify with an id attribute in the form tag

```
<form id='formname' action='mypage.html'>
```