# dropdown selection without clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I don't know where to start, if there is any similar question like mine I would be happy to get some idea! Basically the question says it all, Here is what I would like:

I have a simple dropdown menu. When a selection is made in that drop down menu, a php mysql query is ran where the database will be updated with that value. I have all the pieces, all I need is the code that would be able to kick it all off.

For instance when you hit submit on a form you would typically type out:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//grab information and insert into db

}
```

How would I do this for a drop down selection without having to click the submit button.

Comment: use onchange http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: You could use onchange and an AJAX query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [submit the form without submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867818/submit-the-form-without-submit-button)

Comment: I just need the form to submit when a drop down selection is made. I tried both onchange and AJAX methods and did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be looking for something like this

```
<form id="testform">
<select id="yourselect" name="yourselect" onChange="updateDb()">
 <option value="somevalue">Please select</option>
 <option value="somevalue1">Something</option>
</select>
</form>
```

you Javascript function will look like this

```
function updateDb() {
// I am using jquery for ajax
 $.post("yourserverhandle.php", $("#testform").serialize());
}
```

and this is how your "yourserverhandle.php" looks like

```
<?php
$query = "update yourtable set something='".mysql_escape_string($_POST["yourselect"])."' where id='something'";
.... mysql connect, execute
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax call on drop down change like:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function(){
    // ajax call
});
```

Comment: Did not work, nothing happens when I make a selection in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery/javascript onchange event to perform any type of action on the drop down list. use as follows:

```
$("#select_id").on('change',function(){
 $.post('code url',{paramenters to be stored},function(data){
 alert('inserted');
})
});
```